# Tracking unauthenticated users in Django

Tags: django, session

I need to track unregistered users in my Django website. This is for conversion optimization purposes (e.g. registration funnel, etc).

A method I've used so far is using IP address as a proxy for user_id. For various well-known reasons, this has led to fudged/unreliable results.

Can I sufficiently solve my problem via setting a session variable at server-side? An illustrative example would be great.

---

For example, currently I have a couple of ways in my head. One is doing `request.session["temp_id"] = random.randint(1,1000000)`, and then tracking based on `temp_id`.

Another is setting a session variable every time an unauthorized user hits my web app's landing page, like so:

```
if not request.session.exists(request.session.session_key):
    request.session.create()
```

From here on, I'll simply track them via `request.session.session_key`. Would this be a sound strategy? What major edge-cases (if any) do I need to be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cookies are the simplest approach, but take into consideration that some users can have cookies turned off in their browsers.

So for those users you can use javascript local storage to set some data. This information will get deleted once you close the browser, but it's ok for funneling purposes. Still others can have javascript turned off.

Another approach would be to put custom data(key) in every link of the page when generating the template. in other words you would have the session_id stored in html page and send through url parameters at click. Something similar happens with csrf token. Look into that.

Comment: Regarding cookie: do you mean something like `response.set_cookie('cookie_name', 'cookie_value')`, or are you implying setting variables in the session like I mentioned in the question? Would be good to get an illustrative example of the approach. In a way, the latter approach mirrors the csrf token approach you mentioned.

Comment: request.session.create() is the same as response.set_cookie('session_id', key). The difference is that it also stores data for that key in the database(sessions table) or other repository that you set, but at the HTTP level it behaves the same. They both use the HTTP Cookie mechanism.

Comment: So let's take the login example. Django will store a session_id on the browser with additional information in the database. If someone intercepts the calls between the browser and the webserver and gets the session_id he can make calls to the webserver with that session_id and the server sees him as that user. So I see it as vulnerable as storing everything in the browser. To make it secure you should use HTTPS.

Comment: One benefit to storing session_id is if you use HTTPS, and the client's computer gets hacked, the hacker only gets the session_id instead of all the private info associated with it. For this the webserver should reset the session_id from time to time.